# ALGORITHM - File Naming

Tags: javascript

> You are given an array of desired filenames in the order of their
> creation. Since two files cannot have equal names, the one which comes
> later will have an addition to its name in a form of (k), where k is
> the smallest positive integer such that the obtained name is not used
> yet.
>
> Return an array of names that will be given to the files.
>
> Example
>
> For names = ["doc", "doc", "image", "doc(1)", "doc"], the output
> should be fileNaming(names) = ["doc", "doc(1)", "image", "doc(1)(1)",
> "doc(2)"].

One person posted this solution:

```
const fileNaming = names => {
    const used = {};
    return names.map(name => {
        let newName = name;
        while (used[newName]) {
            newName = `${name}(${used[name]++})`;
        }
        used[newName] = 1;
        return newName;
    });
};
```

I'm having a hard time understanding the `while` block's condition.

`used` is an empty object.

`newName` is a new variable that is equal to the current item in the `names` array.

How does `used[newName]` resolve to a number? `used` is never set to anything other then an empty object.

This is the console output for `console.log(used[newName])`

[image]

Using this input:

```
["dd", 
 "dd(1)", 
 "dd(2)", 
 "dd", 
 "dd(1)", 
 "dd(1)(2)", 
 "dd(1)(1)", 
 "dd", 
 "dd(1)"]
```

Comment: `One person posted this solution` is alarming. Did you come up with your own solution yet?

Comment: please output in your `console.log()` also the values for `name` and `newName`. I have a feeling that you might understand the loop after seeing what's there.

Comment: you say `used is never set to anything other then an empty object.`. But in the sample code, there's this line: `used[newName] = 1;` . It contradicts your statement. ;-) Perhaps that's the key for you to understand the loop?

Comment: I did not come up with my own solution. The platform showcased other users answers and this was the most voted for.

Comment: Hint: Search for "postfix increment operator".

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `{}` is an empty object - and as such, it can contain any number of key-value pairs. A key that is not defined has the value `undefined`, which evaluates to `false` when tested. However, any non-zero, non-NaN numerical value will evaluate to `true`:

```js
console.log({}["a key that does not exist"])                 // undefined
while (undefined) {
    console.log("this should never be printed");             // never executes
}
while ({}["a key that does not exist"]) {
    console.log("this should never be printed");             // never executes
}
if (1) {
    console.log("positive numbers are true");                // writes to console
}
```

You can use objects as maps (even though you can also use *actual* [maps instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in newer code)

A simpler version of the above program would have written

```
return names.map(name => {
    let newName = name;
    while (used[newName] !== undefined) {       // tests for "not undefined"
        newName = `${name}(${used[name]})`;     // uses current value
        used[name] = used[name] + 1;            // sets a larger value            
    }
    used[newName] = 1;                          // sets a value
    return newName;
});
```

Comment: My follow up is probably going to be 'wrong?', but bear with me. `used` is an empty object. We aren't adding anything to it. Wouldn't `use[newName` ALWAYS be undefined? How is it ever returning a truthy value? However, I understand there is a concept I am not fully understanding so thanks for tolerating me haha

Comment: You can add or set key-value entries in a JS object via `object["key"] = value`, which is equivalent to `object.key = value`. However, the `[]` notation allows using a key which is a variable: `let foo = "quix"; object.foo = "bar"` is equivalent to `object["foo"] = "bar"`, while `let foo = "quix"; object[foo] = "bar"` is equivalent to `object["quix"] = "bar"`